# How to fast insert Dict into SqlLite Database?

Tags: python, xml, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a problem with the huge Data of `Users.xml` from Stack Overflow. It has >8mill Data.
I also have `posts.xml` which contains a huge amount of Data.

`Users.xml` = 2,49 GB

`Posts.xml` = 58,3 GB

I will show the communication of my Script from Bottom to Top.

The over method create Table if it does not exist and the inserStatement get the String for the execution statement.

```
def savingDataToDatabase(tableName, element):
    createTable(tableName)
    connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db", isolation_level=None)
    c = connection.cursor() 
    
    if(tableName == "Users"):
        insertStatement = sqlInsertStatement(tableName)
        c.execute(insertStatement,([element["AccountId"], element["Reputation"], element["CreationDate"], element["CreationTime"], element["DisplayName"], element["LastAccessDate"], element["WebsiteUrl"], element["Location"], element["AboutMe"], element["Views"], element["UpVotes"], element["DownVotes"], element["Age"]]))
        connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

`processingUsersXML(element)` returns me a Dict with preprocessed Data.

```
def processingDataForSQL(filename, element):
    if filename == 'Users':
        user = processingUsersXML(element)
        savingDataToDatabase(filename, user)

def getDataFromXml(filename):
    for evt, elem in iterparse('/../usws/stackoverflowDataScience/dumpData/'+str(filename)+'.xml', events=('end',)):
        if elem.tag == 'row':
            element_fields = elem.attrib
            processingDataForSQL(filename, element_fields)
            elem.clear()

def chosenXMLFile():
    getDataFromXml('Users')
    getDataFromXml('Posts')


chosenXMLFile()
```

I hope you guys can help. It just take to much time. It works but it is slow as hell. I have not found any posts which helped me. I seen a post but it does not really helped and I would appreciate it if you can show me by my code where I can modify it.

Comment: Reopening the database and comitting the transaction for every row will of course be slow.

Comment: is there anyway to say like wait till it finishe. I now try to write it down into csv and then insert the csv into sqllite

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new connection and cursor every time, you can pass one cursor to the savingDataToDatabase function:

```
def savingDataToDatabase(tableName, element, cursor):
    if tableName == 'Users':
        insertStatement = sqlInsertStatement(tableName)
        cursor.execute(insertStatement,([element["AccountId"], element["Reputation"], element["CreationDate"], element["CreationTime"], element["DisplayName"], element["LastAccessDate"], element["WebsiteUrl"], element["Location"], element["AboutMe"], element["Views"], element["UpVotes"], element["DownVotes"], element["Age"]]))

def processingDataForSQL(filename, element, cursor):
    if filename == 'Users':
        user = processingUsersXML(element)
        savingDataToDatabase(filename, user, cursor)

def getDataFromXml(filename):
    tableName = filename
    createTable(tableName)
    connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db", isolation_level=None)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for evt, elem in iterparse('/../usws/stackoverflowDataScience/dumpData/'+str(filename)+'.xml', events=('end',)):
        if elem.tag == 'row':
            element_fields = elem.attrib
            processingDataForSQL(filename, element_fields, cursor)
            elem.clear()
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

def chosenXMLFile():
    getDataFromXml('Users')
    getDataFromXml('Posts')

chosenXMLFile()
```